# variable from if statement doesn't correctly count up

Tags: java, boolean

I made a quiz program in java. Everything works, but the counter at the end that counts the amount of questions that have been answered correctly doesn't correctly count up, and always says "3 out of 3" even if all questions are answered wrong. What did I do wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class quiz {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int q1, q2, q3, result;
    boolean onepoint, twopoint, threepoint;

    result = 0;

    onepoint = false;
    twopoint = false;
    threepoint = false;

    System.out.println("Interactive quiz");
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Q1) Which country is new york located in?");
    System.out.println("    1) Canada");
    System.out.println("    2) United States");
    System.out.println("    3) China");
    System.out.println("    4) Russia");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("> ");
    q1 = input.nextInt();

    if (q1 == 2) {
        System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        onepoint = true;
    }
    else if (q1 != 2) {
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        threepoint = false;
    }

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Q2) Which of these animals are not warm blooded?");
    System.out.println("    1) Bear");
    System.out.println("    2) Crow");
    System.out.println("    3) Elephant");
    System.out.println("    4) Frog");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("> ");
    q2 = input.nextInt();

    if (q2 == 4) {
        System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        twopoint = true;
    }
    else if (q2 != 4) {
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        threepoint = false;
    }

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Q3) Which of these plants are carnivorous?");
    System.out.println("    1) Dandelion");
    System.out.println("    2) rafflesia");
    System.out.println("    3) cape sundew");
    System.out.println("    4) titan arum");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("> ");
    q3 = input.nextInt();

    if (q3 == 3) {
        System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        threepoint = true;
    }
    else if (q3 != 3) {
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        threepoint = false;
    }

    System.out.println("");

    if (onepoint = true) {
        result = result + 1;
    }
    if (twopoint = true) {
        result = result + 1;
    }
    if (threepoint = true) {
        result = result + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("Your final score is " + result + " out of 3.");
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that it probably has to do with my if statements near the end. I tried playing around with them, but still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Your `if`-statements should use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Better still, just write `if (onepoint) { ... }`, etc.  `onepoint` and friends are boolean variables. Comparing a boolean variable to `true` is a no-op.

Comment: thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all assignments, `point = true`. Use the equality operator or the boolean as the condition

```
if (onepoint == true) {
    result = result + 1;
}
```

or

```
if (onepoint) {
    result = result + 1;
}
```

If you are using the booleans as point trackers you could consider adding the point values immediately after judging the answer. ex:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result = 0;

    System.out.println("Interactive quiz\n");
    System.out.println("Q1) Which country is new york located in?");
    System.out.println("    1) Canada");
    System.out.println("    2) United States");
    System.out.println("    3) China");
    System.out.println("    4) Russia");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("> ");

    if(input.nextInt() == 2){
        System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        result++
    }else
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Q2) Which of these animals are not warm blooded?");
    System.out.println("    1) Bear");
    System.out.println("    2) Crow");
    System.out.println("    3) Elephant");
    System.out.println("    4) Frog");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("> ");

    if (input.nextInt() == 4) {
        System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        result++;
    }else
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Q3) Which of these plants are carnivorous?");
    System.out.println("    1) Dandelion");
    System.out.println("    2) rafflesia");
    System.out.println("    3) cape sundew");
    System.out.println("    4) titan arum");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("> ");

    if (input.nextInt() == 3) {
        System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        result++;
    }else
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Your final score is " + result + " out of 3.");
}
```